# Javascript Function to be called in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this javascript function which allows me to create my custom alerts by calling it using this `<script>Alert.render('message goes here');</script>`

Javascript:

```
<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
      var winW = window.innerWidth;
      var winH = window.innerHeight;
      var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
      var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
      dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
      dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
      dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
      dialogbox.style.top = "200px";
      dialogbox.style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Image Upload Error!";
      document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
      document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button id = "buttonclose" onclick="Alert.ok()">ok</button>';

    }
    this.ok = function(){
      document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
```

HTML:

```
<div id = "dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id = "dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id = "dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id = "dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id = "dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside the html, I tried calling in the function(Alert.render...) and worked. However, when I tried calling it in the php above the html :

```
echo "<script>Alert.render('message goes here');</script>";
```

It doesn't work at all. Any ideas?

## UPDATE

Here's the php code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btn_sample'])){
  echo "<script>Alert.render('sample message');</script>";
}
```

I added this on the html:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
  <input type = "submit" name = "btn_sample" value = "sample">
</form>
```

Comment: can you show your php page

Comment: you placed the same pieces of code at the same place in your page ? As long as the PHP will execute first and render a HTML page, there sould be no difference.

Comment: @Exprator I added the php sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this** ,

1. I think you are execute the `php` script before document load .
2. Or php included `html` not containing the link of the `this` js script file.

And call the Js function after `window.onload` like this.They will prevent the first one

```
echo "<script>window.onload=function(){Alert.render('message goes here');}</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your render function relies on the elements "dialogoverlay", "Dialogbox", etc. already existing, which they don't if you call the function above your HTML.

You need to either bind your Alert.render() call to the DOMContentLoaded event or just put your scripts at the bottom of your body, which tends to be the preferred practice nowadays.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? You could try putting `console.log()` statement along with your Alert.render() to see if that script  gets executed at all